# How can i change the HTTP response

Tags: java, apache, http, httpclient, httpserver

I'm working on a Java project that i have to create a new specific protocol based on HTTP 1.1, but without the GET and POST methods (with some specifics methods).

The problem that I face is how to change the HTTP header response especially the status line : HTTP 1.1 and change it with the name of my protocol WHATEVER 1.0

And for the rest of methods, Should I just modify the HTTP Api or This could cause some problems ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what your exact problem is? If you're implementing a new protocol then you are completely free to send your own headers. What do you mean by change? It is your own implementation. You can implement whatever you want.

Comment: what i want specially is to change the status line instead of having HTTP/1.1 i want put the name of y own protocol (just the name but the whole process is based on HTTP) .. i see that is possible via the HTTP API source , but i'm not really sur if that can work or not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by HTTP API source? HTTP is only a protocol specification. There exists several implementations. Of course you can take one of them and change the source code according to your own protocol changes. But what to change and how depends on the specific implementation. And why do you want to do that in the first place? What is the benifit to change a widely used protocol and make it incompatible to all other existing implementations? Why don't you create your complety own protocol?

Comment: Of course the whole process rely on HTTP implementation but with little changes especially the status line HTTP/1.1. So it will also be compatible even after change.
I will not use the methods GET, POST of HTTP API, i will use my own created methods.

Comment: Ok, fine. But it is still unclear, what your concrete problem is. You even didn't mention what HTTP implementation you want to rely on. What prevents you from taking one open source implementation, study that code and doing your specific changes?